# Microsoft translator api issue

Tags: java, android, api, bing

I decided to use the `bing api` to translate my system. Below the code will show a `spinner`. I want to let the user choose the language from `spinner`. Then the bing api will based on the selected language to translate the system, is that possible to let bing api to translate values folder(strings.xml)? How do i call it in `java`. Below is my code

```
    public class LanguageActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner spinnerctrl;
    String translatedText;
    Locale[] locales;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_language);
        setTitle(R.string.title_activity_language)
        spinnerctrl = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinnerctrl.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int pos, long id) {

                if (pos == 1) {

                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                            getResources().getString(R.string.YouselectEn), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else if (pos == 2) {

                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                            getResources().getString(R.string.YouselectZH), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else if (pos == 3) {

                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                            getResources().getString(R.string.YouselectHI), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }
                else if (pos == 4) {

                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                            getResources().getString(R.string.YouselectMs), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }


            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing to select", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
                @Override
                protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    Translate.setClientId("plantidentificatio");
                    Translate.setClientSecret("lMFkUM+gG96NFrhhZV649Ix8NxR2SvqXJWpOTOgNq54");
                    try {
                        translatedText = Translate.execute("I should probably set this to something a little less profane", Language.ENGLISH, Language.CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        translatedText = e.toString();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No idea about bing api but here is the code to get all data from `string.xml`

```
Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();
    for (final Field field : fields) {
        String name = field.getName(); //name of string
        try {
            int id = field.getInt(R.string.class); //id of string
            Log.e("name",name);
            Log.e("value", getString(id));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here `Field` should be of type `java.lang.reflect.Field`

Comment: Sorry ,may  i know where to place it?